# Почему Delphi неправильно оперирует над real?

Tags: delphi

Почему при возведении числа в степень, оно почему-то (и как-то) умножается на 0.1 и результат получается не таким, как должен быть? Допустим,, возвожу четыре в третью степень, должно получиться 4 * 4 * 4 = 64, но получается 6.400000000. Почему так?

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  a, b, c, d: real;

begin
  writeln('input a, b, c and d:');
  readln(a, b, c, d);

  if (((b > a) AND (c > b) AND (d > c)) OR ((a > b) AND (b > c) AND (c > d))) then
    begin
      a := exp(3 * ln(a));
      b := exp(3 * ln(b));
      c := exp(3 * ln(c));
      d := exp(3 * ln(d));
    end
  else
    begin
      a := 3;
      b := 3;
      c := 3;
      d := 3;
    end;

  writeln('a = ', a, ' b = ', b, ' c = ', c, ' d = ', d);

  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Точно `6.400000000`, а не `6.400000000e1`?

Comment: @Squidward есть разница?

Comment: [Экспоненциальная запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)

Comment: Потому что так сравнивать вещественные числа нельзя. Рано или поздно "выстрелит". Как показала практика их нужно сравнивать с некой дельтой. Пример: `var delta = 0.00001; begin if (a - b) > delta then ... end;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Почему так?

Потому, что Delphi по умолчанию выводит вещественные числа на консоль в экспоненциальной записи. Попробуйте при выводе указывать форматирование.

Форматирование задаётся следующим образом

```
[переменная]:[общее количество знаков]:[количество знаков после запятой]
```

Например:

```
writeln(a:10:0);
```

Comment: Благодарю большое!